# Printing all items of a list with a double space between them

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I am writing a hangman game in python 3 for my college work. I have this couple lines of code that are being a pain in the ass:

```
word = ['_' for i in range(len(chosen_word))]
print("The word is:", *word)
```

I have this output for a 5 letter word:

```
The word is: _ _ _ _ _
```

But I actually need an output like this (an additional space between items):

```
The word is: _  _  _  _  _
```

Any ideas of how should I do it??

Thanks for the attention and the help! :)

Comment: `('_ ' * len(chosen_word)).rstrip()`

Comment: `print("The word is:", "\ \ ".join(word))` (remove the escapes: SO doesn't render double spaces in comments correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `sep` parameter with a double space:

```
word = ['_' for i in range(len(chosen_word))]
print("The word is:", *word, sep='  ')
```

If you don't want the double space after the ':' use two different prints:

```
word = ['_' for i in range(len(chosen_word))]
print("The word is:", end=' ')
print(*word, sep='  ')
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be:

```
string = '  '.join(words)
print("The word is:", string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = ['_ 'for i in range len(chosen_word)]
print("The word is:", *word)
```

You can simply do this

Comment: That doesn't work because the online system recognizes the space after the last underline which shouldn't be there :/